# Highcharts - stack values for same category

Tags: highcharts

Here is my situation.
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 1 8:10
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 1 8:25
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 1 8:39
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 1 9:50
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 2 10:10
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 2 11:25
One customer viewed my mail on : 2017 nov 2 11:39

Now I want a Line chart with hour on the X axis.
So first point would be: 2017 nov 1 8 with value : 3
Second point should be: 2017 nov 1 9 with value : 1
The a couple of hours without data so value 0.
Then point 2017 nov 2 10 with value : 1
Then point 2017 nov 2 11 with value : 2

I tried using stack, which allows me to correctly display the chart, but the points are incorrect and the tooltip displays a single value, not the combined total.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    tooltip: {
  shared: false
},
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        min: Date.UTC(2013,4,22),
        max: Date.UTC(2013,4,23),
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [1369206795000, 1],
            [1369206795000, 1],
            [1369225421000, 1],
            [1369225421000, 1],
            [1369225421000, 1],
            [1369230934000, 1]
        ],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 05, 22),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        stacking: 'normal'
    }]
});
});
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/elnbado/93Xcu/557/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `stacking`, I would recommend you to use Highstock, force data grouping to group data within one hour and set `approximation` to sum. I prepared an example presenting this in action below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ljemcw2s/